# Why is my SQL statement displaying the function name?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I tried this statement to print all last names in uppercase but this is what I got:

```
UPPER(LAST
----------
BROWN
KERN
HOFFMAN
```

My statement was to print the last names of all employees who's `credit_limit` was greater than 25 in uppercase.

> select UPPER(last_name) from employees where credit_limit>25;

I tried the `UPPER` function but it printed the function and its brackets as well. I want to make it so that it prints this instead:

```
LAST_NAME
----------
BROWN
KERN
HOFFMAN
```

I tried normally printing it as if the `credit_limit` was greater than 25 (without uppercases and I got it the way I wanted it.

> select last_name from employees where credit_limit>25;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you haven't use any column alias for display purpose and so it's using the function name as such. Use a column alias you want to display like

```
select UPPER(last_name) as Last_Name_In_UpperCase
from employees 
where credit_limit > 25;
```